Copy based on different cell info in Sheets
I have a workbook for a school where on one page I have a list of several hundred names, emails, grades, and other info that is generated automatically by Canvas when a student takes an exam. I also have a second sheet with the names, emails, and a unique identifier called a "D-Number" that I need to merge onto the first sheet. For example:
Sheet 1:
Name1 | Email1 | Grade1 | Data1
Name2 | Email2 | Grade2 | Data2
Name3 | Email3 | Grade3 | Data3
Sheet 2:
Name | Email | DNumber
Name | Email | DNumber
Name | Email | DNumber
I need to append the D-Number from the second sheet onto the row with a matching email in the first sheet. I thought this would be a good use for INDEXMATCH or VLOOKUP, but can't get it working as accurately as I would like.
I've made a sample workbook where Sheet3 is the desired result.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-0ixT49BN1PU5Q9f7zAgnS_vfozhDfJ1EjAOmtboeVY/edit?usp=sharing
I tried INDEXMATCH but couldn't figure out the fields I was looking for. VLOOKUP seemed like a good starting point, but I don't know enough about its usage to move forward on my own.


You may try:
=arrayformula(xlookup(B:B,Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!C:C,))



Alternative Formula:
Here's an alternative formula using LAMBDA that you may also use.
Kindly check if it works for you.
Formula:
=BYROW(Sheet2!A1:C6,lambda(x,INDEX(FILTER(x,Sheet2!B1=B1),1,3)))

Sample Output:

Reference:

LAMBDA Function

